# How to check the existence of Attribute in XDocument using LINQ to XML in C#

Tags: c#, linq

i'm having an xml file like

```
 <Root>
   <Child Name="A" />
 </Root>
```

i need to check whether the "Child" element have "val" attribute.if yes , and if the value is greater than zero then need to change the value of a Boolean variable into true;

now i'm using like

```
bool bVal=false

bVal=XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath+"\\foo.xml")
          .Descendants("Child")
          .Select(TEMP => (Int32)TEMP.Attribute("val")).ToList()[0]>0?true:false;
```

this expression is working fine if xml is like

```
<Root>
  <Child Name="A" val ="2" />
</Root>
```

but its throwing an exception if the xml does not contain "val" attribute.

How to modify the above expression(Query) to check the existence of "val" attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, I'd rewrite the query as:

```
bool bVal = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath+"\\foo.xml")
                     .Descendants("Child")
                     .Select(x => (int?) x.Attribute("val"))
                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x != null) > 0;
```

This uses three features:

- Converting `XAttribute` to `int?` instead of `int` will result in the null value if the attribute isn't present
- Using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `ToList()[0]` is more efficient *and* works even if there are no values
- The lifted `>` operator will return `False` when either operand is null

If you want to check whether there *any* positive values, it's even easier:

```
bool bVal = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath+"\\foo.xml")
                     .Descendants("Child")
                     .Select(x => (int?) x.Attribute("val"))
                     .Any(x => x > 0);
```